# Is $|x^3-1|\ge1-x$ true for all real numbers? What is the solution set?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I have to solve following inequality 
$$|x^3-1|\ge1-x$$
my try:

Case 1: let $x\ge 1$, 
$$x^3-1\ge1-x\iff (x-1)(x^2+x+2)\ge 0$$
but $x^2+x+2>0$ for all $x\in R$, hence 
$$x-1\ge 0  \iff x\ge 1$$
which is true.

Case-2: let $x\le 1$, 
$$-(x^3-1)\ge1-x\iff x(x-1)(x+1)\le 0\iff x\in(-\infty, -1]\cup[0, 1]$$
so from above two cases, I get answer: $x\in\mathbb{R}-\{-1<x<0\}$

Am I correct? If not please spot my error. thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

If $x\geq 1$, $1-x\leq 0$ while $|x^3-1|\geq 0$ so the inequality is obviously true. Your approach works as well.

The case $x\leq 1$ is well treated, and I agree with your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to your title: No it is not correct for real numbers. Try $x=-0.6$

Comment: $-0.6$ is not an element of $\mathbb R - \{-1<x<0\}$...

Comment: The title asks "is it true for all real numbers?". I don't understand the downvote. This is also consistent with the result of OP which is $\mathbb{R}-(0,1)$.

Comment: I retracted my downvote.

Comment: @msm: The title is misleading: what the OP wants is the solution set of that inequation.

Comment: I know @AlexM. I had read until "My Try..." when I answered. Then I realized how carelessly the question is asked, when the answer was already downvoted (which is still a perfect answer to the question being asked)